# Estimation of calcium EDTA

Tags: experimental-chemistry

How can i estimate calcium EDTA in a given sample?
We tried estimation by using mercuric nitrate but in vain we cant get a sharp end point.

Comment: @JinnySara Could you provide more information about the sample?

Answer (score 1):

Something crossed my mind - you could try titrating with Fe(III) standard using SCN- as indicator. First excess of Fe3+ would produce a sharp end-point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information you gave me. Actually it helped mei a lot and v did this using ferric ammonium sulphate using potassium thiocyanate as indicator which will give you a blood red colour. We recently manufactured calcium disodium edatate hard gelatin capsule so for that we were trying to develop a method